# AuthorizationError when confirming SNS subscription over HTTP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm writing a simple SNS client that is meant to subscribe itself to an SNS topic and then listen for notifications. I can successfully submit a `sns.subscribe` request, but when I pick up the `SubscriptionConfirmation` POST message from AWS and try and respond using `sns.confirmSubscription` I get an `AuthorizationError` returned:

```
[AuthorizationError: User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/mv-user is not authorized to perform: SNS:ConfirmSubscription on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx:*]
```

If I use exactly the same Token and TopicArn in a GET query to the server the subscription confirmation works fine, with no authentication.

Any ideas why it's not working? My SNS topic is wide open with publish/subscribe permissions set to 'Everyone'.

For reference, my code is something like this:

```
        var params = {
            TopicArn: topicArn,  // e.g. arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx:yyy
            Token: token         // long token extracted from POST body
        };

        sns.confirmSubscription(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // BOOOM - keep getting here with AuthorizationError
            } else {
                // Yay. Worked, but never seem to get here :(
            }
        });
```

However, if I navigate to the URL similar to this in a browser (i.e. completely unauthenticated), it works perfectly:

```
http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&Token=<token>&TopicArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-east-1%3Axxx%3Ayyy&Version=2010-03-31
```

The only differences seem to be the inclusion of 'Authorization' and 'Signature' headers in the programmatic version (checked using Wireshark).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

## Update

In my code, if I just programatically do a simple GET request to the `SubscribeURL` in the `SubscriptionConfirmation` message this works fine. Just seems odd that the `confirmSubscription` API call doesn't work. Will probably stick to this workaround for now.

## Update 2

Also get the same error when calling `sns.unsubscribe` although, again, calling the `UnsubscribeURL` in each notification works. Seems other people have run into that issue too but can't find any solutions.

Comment: what are the IAM permissions for `mv-user`?

Comment: The user has no specific IAM permissions or roles. I've tried various settings for the user in the SNS Topic policy. Will update post to show policy when I'm back in the office.

Comment: And what's really frustrating, this doc page (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/UsingIAMwithSNS.html) says "However, the ConfirmSubscription and Unsubscribe actions do not require authentication, which means that even if you specify those actions in a policy, IAM won't restrict users' access to those actions."

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue while developing my application.
The way I ended up solving it is the following:

1. go to IAM and click on your user
2. go to the permissions tab and click on "Attach Policy"
3. use the filter to filter for "AmazonSNSFullAccess"
4. Attach the above policy to your user.

The above should take care of it.

If you wanna be fancy you can create a custom policy that is based on "AmazonSNSFullAccess" and apply it to you user instead.

The custom policy would be something similar to the following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "sns:ConfirmSubscription"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "YOUR_RESOURCE_ARN_SHOULD_BE_HERE"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all:

```
[AuthorizationError: User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/mv-user is not authorized to perform: SNS:ConfirmSubscription on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx:*]
```

is basically telling you that the IAM user you're using to call ConfirmSubscription doesn't have the proper permissions to do so. Best bet is to update the permissions for that IAM user, specifically adding `ConfirmSubscription` permissions.

(Based on your comments, even though the documentation says otherwise, the error is pretty specific... might be worth following up directly with AWS about this issue, since either the error message or documentation is incorrect).

Comment: Yeah, it seems obvious but I've tried no end of permissions and nothing seems to work. In fact there doesn't even seem to be a 'Confirm Sub' permission anyway! Seems odd that the unauthorised HTTP GET version works. Will dig a little more and add permissions I've tried when I get a chance. Cheers.